# Merge php and php-5.4 tags into just php?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

We have a [php](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php) tag, and we also have a [php-5.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php-5.4) tag.

Ultimately, they're both PHP, and I see no reason to have separate PHP tags for each version (the same reasoning was the primary drive, as far as I can tell, for [php5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php5) to be an alias of [php](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php)).

Can we take the [php-5.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php-5.4) tag and just have that be an alias of [php](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/php)?  Otherwise we'll have a thousand PHP tags which we don't need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, php-5.4 should be a synonym of php5 which should be a synonym of php